# MySQL: Selecting rows with event time earlier than 1 week from a specific event_time

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I have a table which contains the following data:

```
    ID        Event_time               Event_type
    0      2016-05-11 17:26:03.0            1
    0      2017-06-13 19:29:03.0            2
    0      2017-06-13 13:56:05.0            3
    0      2016-05-13 17:20:37.0            1
    1      2016-09-20 16:20:03.0            0
    1      2016-11-11 20:12:03.0            2
    2      2016-11-15 17:26:03.0            1
    2      2016-12-02 15:06:00.0            2
    2      2016-12-02 15:00:03.0            0
```

Each ID has `Event_type = 2`. Now I want to select only that data, which is 1 week or less older than date from `Event_type = 2` for each `ID` separately.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT*FROM my_table WHERE EVENT_TIME IN (SELECT DATE_SUB(EVENT_TIME, INTERVAL 7 DAY) FROM my_table where EVENT_TYPE='2')
```

but it doesn't give me desired output, which should be:

```
ID        Event_time               Event_type
0      2017-06-13 19:29:03.0            2
0      2017-06-13 13:56:05.0            3
1      2016-11-11 20:12:03.0            2
2      2016-12-02 15:06:00.0            2
2      2016-12-02 15:00:03.0            0
```

I think that something doesn't work properly with `DATE_SUB` function, but I don't have any idea how to fix it.

EDITED:
Dates with Event_type = 2 should either be in the output.

Comment: Why would event_type = 2 appear in the result?

Comment: Sorry I didn't write that accidentally, dates with event_type=2 should be in the output. Thanks @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention "for each ID separately", yet you don't check for that in your query.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table WHERE EVENT_TIME > (
    SELECT DATE_SUB(MAX(EVENT_TIME), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
    FROM my_table mt /*note that I used a different alias here for the table...*/
    WHERE EVENT_TYPE='2'
      AND mt.ID = my_table.ID /*...so that I can distinguish between the ID in the subquery and the outer query*/
)
```

Comment: It looks OK, but gives me an error: Unknown column 'my_table.ID' in 'where clause'. What do you think, what's wrong?

Comment: That you either don't have a table called my_table or that you don't have a column ID. I just took the names like you used them in your query in the question. Of course you have to rename them accordingly, when this are not the real names.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bba8f/1 but according to this, your query doesn't give any output.

Comment: Fixed it. With the IN()  clause you were comparing exact dates. But you want to compare on a range (of time). I added the MAX() clause in the subquery, so that it returns only one result.

Comment: Thank you, it works. One more question and I hope that it will be the last :) What If my_table is a temporary table? I have an error: 'can't reopen table: my_table'. I read in the Internet, that I should create another temporary table, but still it isn't appropriate solution for me. Maybe you've got any advices for me with temp tables? Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: You can't use a temporary table for this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-table-problems.html Simple solution: Don't use temporary tables. All you probably gain from them is, that they are automatically dropped. Do this yourself. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-temporary-table.html

Comment: Yes, but my database is larger than I showed you in my question. I have there either data which inluded ID's, which don't have Event_type = 2. To make a table like you can see in my question, I made a query: 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempT1 (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM my_table WHERE Event_type=2) ORDER BY ID);

Comment: Yeah, so? Just don't make it temporary. Have you read the links I posted? Do you mistakenly think it's a memory table?

Comment: OK, I change it. But my database has 260k rows and I'm still waiting for making my query done. Should this process be so long? It lasts 15 minutes and still doesn't give any results...

Comment: Probably not. But debugging this really goes too far for this comment section. Post a new question with the results of following queries: `show indexes from <your_table>` for all tables in your query and `explain <your_query>`. With proper indexes you might not even need a (temporary) table. 260k rows isn't really much. Your server configuration may also be the cause. Post how much memory you have, how many CPUs and the content of your my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` clause will make is so that the date must correspond exactly to the given select.

Try:

```
SELECT*FROM my_table WHERE EVENT_TIME < DATE_SUB(EVENT_TIME, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND EVENT_TYPE='2'
```